# tmux disregarding the configuration file

Tags: linux, tmux

I just installed tmux on Ubuntu 10.04 and tried to remap the prefix key to `C-a` by creating the file `~/.tmux.conf` with these lines:

```
set-option -g prefix C-a
unbind-key C-b
```

When starting tmux, both regularly and with `-f ~/.tmux.conf`, the prefix is effectively the same default `C-b`

There are no errors or warnings whatsoever.

Any idea what's wrong with the loading of the conf?

Comment: It Works For Me™. Try running `strace -s9999 -f -o tmux.strace tmux -c true` and post the output of `grep -C5 'tmux\.conf' tmux.strace`.

Comment: I had this same problem, no existing sessions, ('tmux ls' reported connection refused, i.e. not running), but it still wasn't reading the conf file. I was launching it with a CWD somewhere in /usr, but when I switched to ~/ and launched tmux, it processed the conf file. It's weird behaviour, but that's something to check.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

The file ~/.tmux.conf is loaded when the tmux server is first started. So if there are existing tmux sessions, starting a new session with `tmux` does not result in reloading the .tmux.conf file. Try restarting tmux server: Use the command `tmux list-sessions` to see if there are existing sessions. Exit them (e.g. `tmux attach` then kill all windows and exit). Once all sessions are gone, try `tmux` again. This time the rebinding should work.

Comment: `killall tmux` or `tmux kill-server` will get the job done too

Comment: I used `killall tmux` and `tmux kill-server` and still my conf is not loaded. I can confirm it is valid, since using `:source-file ~/.tmux.conf` in tmux does actually make the config changes! Can't figure out what is causing this behavior.

Comment: I wonder why reloading the config wasn't mentioned in this answer. It sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. Any ideas on that?

Comment: `tmux ls` short version of `tmux list-sessions`.
`tmux a` short version to attach to last used session.
`:kill-server` to kill all sessions at once.

Answer (score 67):

To reload your ~/.tmux.conf without killing your session, you can simply do:

```
<prefix> :source-file /absolute/path/to/your/.tmux.conf
```

where `<prefix>` is `<C-b>` by default.

Comment: You can add the following to .tmux.conf to use Ctrl-A r to reload: `bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "Config reloaded..."`

Comment: +1 for pointing out the necessity of absolute path

Comment: Note that this was not enough for my use case. I had added some styles to my .tmux.conf, then removed them and reloaded, but some of them were not overwritten just by sourcing the file without them. I had to actively kill the session, and then the next session I created had the correct styling.

Answer (score 27):

run inside your tmux session:

```
tmux source-file /absolute/path/to/your/.tmux.conf
```

Comment: Note: this will not affect the current tmux window (obviously), but all new tmux windows.

Comment: If your admins start tmux automatically, add this line to your ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 4):

There's also a default keyboard shortcut binding to reload your `~/.tmux.conf`, at least in my installation: `C-b r`. If you hit `C-b ?` it brings up a list of all bound keyboard shortcuts, so you can see if you have one already defined.

Comment: That is specific to your installation/configuration. By default, `<prefix> r` is bound to `refresh-client` (what you describe would be something like `source ~/.tmux.conf`).

Answer (score 3):

## 12 years ago

A [hero](https://superuser.com/users/42315/gilles-so-stop-being-evil) left a [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/188491/tmux-disregarding-the-configuration-file#comment191423_188491).

> It Works For Me™. Try running `strace -s9999 -f -o tmux.strace tmux -c true` and post the output of `grep -C5 'tmux\.conf' tmux.strace`. –
> Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'
> Sep 14, 2010 at 20:24

### A master class in understatement

With no fanfaronade they dropped a single sentence in a comment that should have been, not only *an answer* but, *the answer*. Not only *the answer* to this question, but **the reference answer** to an entire class of questions.

### Breaking it down

What does `strace -s9999 -f -o tmux.strace tmux -c true` mean?

It's sort of like 2 commands in 1. The main command is `tmux` but it is given a "prefix"/"wrapper" called `strace`. This is very similar to running `time df` to measure how much time it takes to run the `df` command.

#### `strace`   `-s9999`   `-f`   `-o tmux.strace`

```
$ man strace | grep -A1 ^NAME
NAME
       strace - trace system calls and signals

$ man strace | grep -EA10 '^ *DESCRIPTION($| )'
DESCRIPTION
       In the simplest case strace runs the specified command until it  exits.   It
       intercepts  and  records  the system calls which are called by a process and
       the signals which are received by a process.  The name of each system  call,
       its  arguments  and its return value are printed on standard error or to the
       file specified with the -o option.

       strace is a useful diagnostic, instructional, and  debugging  tool.   System
       administrators,  diagnosticians and trouble-shooters will find it invaluable
       for solving problems with programs for  which  the  source  is  not  readily
       available  since  they  do not need to be recompiled in order to trace them.

$ man strace | grep -EA4 '^ *-s($| )'
       -s strsize
       --string-limit=strsize
                   Specify the maximum string size to print (the  default  is  32).
                   Note  that  filenames  are not considered strings and are always
                   printed in full.

$ man strace | grep -EA6 '^ *-f($| )'
       -f
       --follow-forks
                   Trace child processes as they are created  by  currently  traced
                   processes as a result of the fork(2), vfork(2) and clone(2) sys‐
                   tem calls.  Note that -p PID  -f  will  attach  all  threads  of
                   process  PID  if  it  is  multi-threaded,  not  only thread with
                   thread_id = PID.

$ man strace | grep -EA8 '^ *-o($| )'
       -o filename
       --output=filename
                   Write the trace output to  the  file  filename  rather  than  to
                   stderr.   filename.pid  form  is used if -ff option is supplied.
                   If the argument begins with '|' or '!', the rest of the argument
                   is  treated as a command and all output is piped to it.  This is
                   convenient for piping the debugging output to a program  without
                   affecting  the redirections of executed programs.  The latter is
                   not compatible with -ff option currently.
```

#### `tmux`   `-c true`

```
$ man tmux | grep -EA4 '^ *-c($| [^ ]*$)'
     -c shell-command
                   Execute shell-command using the default shell.  If necessary,
                   the tmux server will be started to retrieve the default-shell
                   option.  This option is for compatibility with sh(1) when tmux
                   is used as a login shell.

$ man true | grep -A1 ^NAME
NAME
       true - do nothing, successfully
```

### Why...

#### use `-c` with tmux?

Since we only really care about the startup process of `tmux`, we don't need to use it interactively. Therefore, we will instruct it to run a command in place of our normal interactive shell.

#### use `true` as the tmux command?

Because it exits very quickly and will keep our log short.

#### use `-o tmux.strace` with strace?

It's just file to store the output. Naming things is hard. It was not important to match the basename or the extension to anything else.

#### use `-f` with strace?

I'll assume you read the excerpt from the man page and not *redundacate*. Any reasonably complex application is going to create child processes. Since `tmux` is magnificently complex, we definitely want to strace those too.

#### use `-s9999` with strace?

Since we are writing the output to a file, we don't need line truncated to fit our terminal width. Set it large. Deal with displaying it later if it's a problem.

### Why do *any of this*?

If by ***any***, you mean write this long-ass answer...

1. Because I train engineering teams and will point them to this answer.
2. Because Giles...

   - is freaking hero
   - had 0 upvotes on their comment for 10+ years
   - has gone unnoticed for too long, and I refuse to let it continue

If you don't see why this process is **The Way** to answer a question like
*"Any idea what's wrong with the loading of the conf?"*
then I would refer you to the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250888/167351)

It is not only *questioners* who fall into the XY Problem. It **extremely** common for answers to ~make this mistake~ do this also. In this case, many answers to this question instruct the reader how to load/reload a config file after the process has started. That suggests ignoring the fact the process fails to load the file as it should.

If you have made it this far, what I want you to take away is take it's only okay to ignore a failure if you are:

- moving past a blocker so that you can remove yourself as a blocker for others
- going to come back a fix the problem correctly later

#### The Take Away

Many problems can be distilled down to "What's wrong with the loading of the file?". That question should tickle a spidey-sense in the form of "Is it trying to load the file? What is happening when it tries?"

You can/should[?] use `strace` solve anything that can be be questioned as:

- What is this process trying to do?
- What is **it** experiencing when it tries to do that [thing it's trying to do]?

Often, it is **not a failure of the process** to do a thing, but **a failure of the user** expecting the process to do a thing. And, the process experiences a lot of things that the user is not informed of.

Enough with the abstract pontification. Let's consider an example:

```
$ tmux kill-server; rm tmux.strace; strace -s9999 -f -o tmux.strace tmux -c true
no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default

$ ls -lh tmux*
-rw-r--r-- 1 bruno bruno  21K Jun 11 10:58 tmux-client-18358.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 bruno bruno 324M Jun 11 10:58 tmux-server-18360.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 bruno bruno 342K Jun 11 13:48 tmux.strace

$ grep 'tmux\.conf' tmux.strace
521744 readlink("/etc/tmux.conf", 0x7ffe2c0446d0, 1023) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
521744 readlink("/home/bruno/.tmux.conf", 0x7ffe2c0446d0, 1023) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
521744 readlink("/home/bruno/.config/tmux/tmux.conf", 0x7ffe2c0446d0, 1023) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

$ ls -lA /home/bruno/.config/tmux
-rw-r--r-- 1 bruno bruno 307 Jun 10 20:29 tmux.config
```

Do you see it? Look at the output of the last 2 commands. Maybe it would help if I showed you how I fix it.

```
$ mv ~/.config/tmux/tmux.config \
    ~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf

$ tmux kill-server; rm tmux.strace; strace -s9999 -f -o tmux.strace tmux -c true
no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default

$ grep -A2 '\.config/tmux/tmux\.conf' tmux.strace
527872 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/bruno/.config/tmux/tmux.conf", O_RDONLY) = 8
527872 newfstatat(8, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=307, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
527872 read(8, "set -sg escape-time 0\nset -g mode-keys vi\n\n# remap prefix from 'C-b' to 'C-f'\nset-option -g prefix C-f\nunbind-key C-b\nbind-key C-f send-prefix\n\n# split panes using | and -\nbind | split-window -h\nbind - split-window -v\n# bind \"\33OA\" # scroll natural up\n# bind \"\33OB\" # scroll natural down\nunbind '\"'\nunbind %\n\n", 4096) = 307
```

Note: That last line is the entire contents of my (previously misnamed) `~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf` file.

Answer (score 2):

I quit and reopened my terminal and that's the only way I could get it to work again. Not sure why.

using Terminal on Mac OSX

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I was using [tmux-next](https://code.dogfood.paddev.net/~pi-rho/+recipe/tmux-next-daily).

Initially I solved it just by passing the config file explicitly `tmux -f ~/.tmux.conf` as the question here points out. (I had already aliased tmux-next to tmux.)

Then I realised tmux-next is using tmux-next.conf, so just symlink it if using this and only need to run the next tmux version.

`ln -s ~/.tmux.conf ~/.tmux-next.conf`

Answer (score 1):

`tmux` not load `~/.tmux.conf` automatically, you must source manually, for the first time that you install `tmux` or  every time that you change anything in `~/.tmux.conf` by:

```
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

- it's different with vim (vim source files after every time opened)