# tmux disregarding the configuration file even when no sessions exist

Tags: tmux

This question is similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/188491/tmux-disregarding-the-configuration-file), but in this case running "killall tmux" or "tmux kill-server" is not effective. Running "tmux list-sessions" returns "failed to connect to server".

Running "source ~/.tmux.conf" inside of tmux runs the conf file and everything works as expected.

Comment: have you tried adding the -f flag to the tmux startup?  i.e. `tmux -f ~/.tmux.conf`

Comment: interestingly that also doesn't work.

Comment: can you put your tmux.conf somewhere to look at?  (gist/pastebin/etc)

Comment: the only command in the file is "set -gw mode-keys emacs"

Comment: newline at the end of file?

Comment: nope no newline (and adding one doesn't break a manual call from in tmux i.e. "source ~/.tmux.conf").

Comment: you can try to strace/dtruss the tmux start and look to see if it actually tries to load the config.  The newline idea was a bit of a stretch, was thinking if your file didn't end with newline it may screw up the automatic load.  I'm out of ideas at this point.  post back if you figure it out.