# Using tmux with both emacs and vim

Tags: tmux

What is the best default key binding for tmux and why if one sometimes uses emacs and sometimes uses vim (on Linux Mint 12)? Ctrl-b is OK, but that conflicts a bit with the bash shell and emacs.

Comment: One that makes sense to you. Duh?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a good answer in a related post: [What's the least conflicting prefix/escape sequence for screen or tmux?](https://superuser.com/questions/74492/whats-the-best-prefix-escape-sequence-for-screen-or-tmux/385868#385868)

And I've gone with Ctrl-\. Below is my ~/.tmux-conf:

```
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
set-window-option -g window-status-current-bg blue
set-window-option -g automatic-rename on
set-option -g status-keys vi
set-option -g history-limit 100000
set-option -g base-index 1
set-option -s escape-time 0
setw -g mode-mouse on
set-option -g mouse-select-pane on

# We won't worry about sending C-\ to any programs
# bind-key C-\ send-prefix

# hit C-\ twice to go to last window
bind-key C-\ last-window
bind-key b set-option status

bind-key / command-prompt "split-window 'exec man %%'"
# vim's definition of a horizontal/vertical split is reversed from tmux's
bind s split-window -v
bind v split-window -h

# move around panes with hjkl, as one would in vim after pressing ctrl-w
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R

# resize panes like vim
bind < resize-pane -L 10
bind > resize-pane -R 10
bind - resize-pane -D 10
bind + resize-pane -U 10

# C-b is not acceptable, due to emacs, bash, and vim
unbind-key C-b
set-option -g prefix C-\
```

Comment: This doesn't work out of the box for Mac. I went back to Ctrl-a, and switched to vim bindings and evil-mode for emacs, so I don't hit ctrl-a anymore for beginning of line.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly prefer `C-]`, which doesn't conflict with vi bindings, and conflicts with the default `abort-recursive-edit` binding in Emacs.  I use that rarely enough, and in nasty enough circumstances, that typing it twice isn't a big drama.

Comment: In context to " _which doesn't conflict with vi bindings_ ", it does if you use tags.  `:h tagsrch.txt` and `:h CTRL-]`

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Ctrl-/ for a while and haven't found to conflict with anything at least in vim/bash.  I don't use emacs so I don't know if it conflicts with anything important in it.

Also a small note I believe I had to bind it to C-_ to get it to work since that is the actual key it sends.

Comment: C-\ and C-_ are definitely different characters; respectively, they are 0x1C “File Separator” and 0x1F “Unit Separator”. See the table in [Wikipedia’s ASCII control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters).

Answer (score 1):

I chose Ctrl+Alt+b, i.e.

```
unbind C-b
set -g prefix M-C-b
```

Answer (score 1):

I use C-\. Note that you need to escape it with single quotes:

```
unbind-key C-b
set-option -g prefix C-'\'
```

Comment: As a note, this conflicts with vim's evaluate expression shortcut key.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've come across for this is using just `.  The only place this causes me problems is pasting in code directly (with system buffers), otherwise it's the perfect solution.

```
set -g prefix `
bind-key ` send-prefix
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good idea is to go for `M-F3`.
It doesn't conflict with emacs and vi, the combinaison is rather convenient, is it' rather closed to the M-F2 and M-F1 used for run command and virtualdesktops menu.

[I'm using emacs, and starting some vim (inside emacs for now) and using linuxMint cinnamon for distro]