# vim : <c-a> occupied from tmux/screen

Tags: vim, gnu-screen, tmux

I use screen/tmux and vim.
In vim, I can't use `<c-a>` for increment a number, `<c-a>` is occupied from screen/tmux.

any suggestion for a simple map for increment a number ?

I try with

```
nnoremap <c-A> <c-a>
```

but, with this I have push down two times `<c-A>`

```
<c-A><c-A>
```

and with `<c-X>` never decrement the number

Answer (score 2):

With screen, i've no problem. For doing a Control-a you have to do : C-a a

```
$ screen
$ vim foobar

type 'i' for insertion mode
type '1' 
type 'ESC'
type C-a a
```

=> 1 becomes 2

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also dot `.` can repeat this so there's no need to do the same awkward escaping over and over.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/382102/using-tmux-with-both-emacs-and-vim/382103#382103) will probably help out.  To repeat my answer from there, I prefer `C-]` as the tmux / screen key, because it doesn't get in the way of normal bindings in either vim or emacs.

Comment: `C-]` is used by vim to jump to the definition of a keyword.

Comment: Yes `C-]` is too much important (ctags), therefor I use `C-x` for tmux / screen key. I know it does decrement in vim, I don't use that too often in vim in screen.

Comment: `C-x` actually used for all autocomplete functions (e.g. `C-xC-o` = omnicomplete).