# How do I bind the tmux prefix key to C-'?

Tags: tmux

I'd like to set my tmux prefix key to Ctrl-apostrophe, but when I use `set-option prefix "C-'"` or `set-option prefix C-"'"`, tmux complains that "unknown key: C-'". Similarly for ` and :. Is there a way to bind these keys?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most terminal emulators only generate special output for a restricted set keys when used in combination with the Control modifier key. The apostrophe key is one of the keys that does **not** generate any special output sequence (it ether does nothing or just outputs a regular apostrophe).

See Wikipedia’s “[ASCII control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters)” and “[How control characters map to keyboards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#How_control_characters_map_to_keyboards)”.

You can check to see if your terminal emulator generates any output for Control-`'`, by typing it into `cat -v`, or at a shell prompt (in most common shells) after typing a Control-V.

If it does generate some special output (not just `'`), then you might be able to bind it in *tmux* if the control code/sequence is known to *tmux*. The list of keys names that *tmux* recognizes is in its manpage under the “Key Bindings” section. *tmux* will only recognize special keys if the terminfo entry for your TERM outside of *tmux* defines them (see `man terminfo` for the “capability” names and `infocmp` for the ones your TERM defines); if needed, you can extend your system’s terminfo entry just for *tmux* with its `terminal-overrides` configuration variable (or recompile your own custom entry with `tic`).

If it does not generate any special output then you would have to somehow reconfigure it to do so (if that is possible); you might have it generate the same code as `^]`, or the sequence for “F20” (if it is defined in your TERM’s entry when outside *tmux*).

Comment: I finally got around to switching from gnome-terminal to xterm, so I now know _how_ to remap Ctrl+' (the translations resource). However, by setting the XTerm*modifyOtherKeys:1 resource, I was able to get Ctrl-' to generate "^[[27;5;39~" instead of an apostrophe. Now I wonder if there's a way to get tmux to recognize that, despite it not showing up under `infocmp -L xterm-256color`...

Comment: You can use `terminal-overrides` to modify bits of the terminfo entry that *tmux* uses. For example: `set -g terminal-overrides "*:kf20=\e[27;5;39~"` and `set -g prefix F20`

Comment: Interesting. I wound up taking your original suggestion. The magic translations string is the following: `*VT100*translations: #override \n !Ctrl<Key>apostrophe: string("\033[34;1~")`.  infocmp reported "`key_f20=\E[19;2~`", so I had to guess-and-check for the key tmux would recognize.